# Vista x64 - looking for 64bit signed bluetooth drivers for Broadcom BCM2045 chipset

Tags: windows-vista, drivers, 64-bit

I'm looking for 64bit **signed** bluetooth drivers for Broadcom BCM2045 chipset.

Drivers available for [AirLive BT-201USB](http://www.aienter code hererlive.com/product/product_3.jsp?pdid=PD1217409688986) based on this chipset have 64bit version but aren't signed and therefore I can't install them on Vista x64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to contact Broadcom support? You could write an email to their Bluetooth customer service:

http://www.broadcom.com/products/bluetooth_support.php

(bt-info at broadcom.com)

Comment: Thanks for info. I'll try to contact them. From what I know they license their bluetooth drivers only to manufacturers and an end-user can't obtain them directly from Broadcom.

Comment: I found this page http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php, with nice tool which detects, downloads and installs the latest version of Broadcom bluetooth drivers. This way I got installed drivers version 6.2.0.8900 dated 2009-04-22 which are 64bit and signed.

Answer (score 1):

I will try looking for a signed version of the drivers for you, but you **can** install unsigned drivers on Vista (32 or 64), it is just not advised by Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks David. I know I can do it but would like to have signed drivers.